# Ghost CMS s3 storage adaptor npm module ContentPath

Tags: npm, ghost-blog

I've got an issue using storage adaptors and ghost ran as an npm module. When I run ghost I get error saying "cant find module", and its looking for the npm module in my theme directory, rather than in the project root.

project/node_modules/ghost/core/server/adapters/storage/s3

Its something to do with the contentPath, but I'm not sure how to fix this. This is my contentpath:

```
  paths: {
      contentPath: path.join(__dirname, "content")
    }
```